# Pyspark - Sum and aggregate based on a key in RDD

Tags: pyspark, aggregate, rdd

I have the below RDD.

```
[[1,101,001,100,product1],
 [2,102,001,105,product2],
 [3,103,002,101,product3]]
```

Expected output is

```
[('001', ['product1','100'],['product2','105']),('002',['product3','101'])]
```

Comment: A little more context would help answering this question. What do you want to aggregate? What would be the key? I am right now I would assume the 3rd item in the nested list is your key? Items 1 & 2 of the nested lists should be disregarded?

Comment: Yes. you are correct. 3rd field is the key and the items 1 and 2 can be ignored

Comment: imho SO is not a platform, where you just throw a problem over the fence (especially, when little context is provided) and hope somebody throws back an answer. You need to show, that you have already put thought and research into a problem. Have a look at SO-Meta's [__How do I ask a good question?__](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It will make it much easier for others to get their head around your problem and help you find the answer you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling in a holiday mood, so there you go:

I assumed, that items 3 & 5 in your nested lists should be Strings...

**Creation of RDD:**

```
ls = [[1,101,"001",100,"product1"],
 [2,102,"001",105,"product2"],
 [3,103,"002",101,"product3"]]

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(ls)
```

This would afford `rdd1` as:

```
[[1, 101, '001', 100, 'product1'],
 [2, 102, '001', 105, 'product2'],
 [3, 103, '002', 101, 'product3']]
```

**Mapping:**

```
# discard items 1 & 2; set item 3 as key
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda row: (row[2], [row[4], row[3]]))
rdd2.collect() 

> [('001', ['product1', 100]),
>  ('001', ['product2', 105]),
>  ('002', ['product3', 101])]

# group by key and map values to a list
rdd3 = rdd2.groupByKey().mapValues(list)
rdd3.collect()

> [('001', [['product1', 100], ['product2', 105]]), 
>  ('002', [['product3', 101]])]
```

It is not quite the output you're interested in, but then the RDD is keyed..